# How can I get BayetasMod for Grid 2 installed on Mac?

Tags: steam, macos, grid-2

The instructions for Bayetas Mod (downloaded from http://www.racedepartment.com/downloads/bayetas-mod.439/) are applicable only to Windows. Have you managed to install this on Mac, and if so, what did you do?

The straightforward translation from Windows paths to Unix paths does not seem to work. When I give the Unix path to the `mods.xml` file on the `-mod` command line switch, Grid 2 gives a dialog with the error message "unable to open the mod configuration file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Games and Mods rely very heavily on knowing what platform they are targeting.   This makes it very difficult to port complex modifications between platform versions of the game even if they seem to be similar on the outside.  Simply re-targeting the XML will not aid in handling numerous internal function calls that will not be recognized outside the target platform.

There are two 'solutions' I can think of.

The first is to recompile or to make a similar mod using Mac versions of the modification studio targeting a mac version of the game.

The second is more of a cheat but is far easier.   With the power of modern computers it is possible to emulate more modern OS's inside each other.   Host a VM on your Mac and emulate a windows OS, install grid 2 and load up all your windows mods.

I use Oracle's free VM to do this for numerous games.
Link : https://www.virtualbox.org/

So my solution is not to run it on Mac OS. . .or to make a different mod.   Neither of which actually solves your issue.  Sadly I do not know of any quick workaround for cross platform software, and if we find one we will be very rich.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure that for this download you can only get it on windows, so you cannot get it on mac unless you find one online. This is because the game was made compatible for windows, not mac so you would have to find some program to "translate" the game. Good luck!